# Rails - Duplicate and Customize Form Input Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I am creating a form using simple_form and am unable to send four form params to `Form#Create`:
1) date, 2) deposit, 3) notes and 4) returned_tag.

I have double checked the list of strong params, as well as the form view. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

As @micah pointed out, the issue seems to be by the duplication of the `date` input field. I duplicated them in order to get custom options for each (start and end dates), based upon which member type was selected (using the jQuery code below to insert the custom `date` field). What would be the correct way to go about this without reproducing the above error? In other words, is my only option to create separate attributes in my database under different names?

Form Controller:

```
class FormsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user
  before_action :admin_user, only: :destroy

  def index
    @forms = Form.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 20)
  end

  def show
    @form = Form.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => @form.last_name + '_' + @form.first_name + '_' + @form.created_at.strftime("%d %b %Y"),
        :template => 'forms/show.pdf.erb',
        :show_as_html => params[:debug].present?
      end
    end
  end

  def new
    @form = Form.new
  end

  def create

    @form = Form.new(form_params)

    signature = Paperclip.io_adapters.for(params[:form][:base64])
    signature.original_filename = "signature.png"
    @form.signature = signature

    if @form.save
      flash[:success] = "The form has been successfully created!"
      redirect_to @form
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @form = Form.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @form = Form.find(params[:id])
    if @form.update_attributes(form_params)
      flash[:success] = "Form has been updated!"
      redirect_to @form
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    Form.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Form deleted"
    redirect_to forms_path
  end

  private

  def form_params
    params.require(:form).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :address, :member_type, :date, :base64, :children, :hour, :interaction, :new_tag, :returned_tag, :deposit, :notes)
  end
end
```

New form view:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Create form') %>
<h1>Create a new form</h1>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <%= simple_form_for(@form, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>

      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.input :first_name, error: false %>
      <%= f.input :last_name, error: false %>
      <%= f.input :email, error: false %>
      <%= f.input :phone, error: false %>
      <%= f.input :address, error: false %>
      <%= f.input :member_type, collection: Form::MEMBERSHIPS, include_blank: true, error: false %>

      <div id="children">
        <%= f.input :children, collection: Form::CHILDREN, error: false, include_blank: true %>
      </div>

      <div id="date-select-kollel">
        <p>Please provide proof of Kollel Attendence</p>
        <%= f.input :date, start_year: Time.now.year - 5, end_year: Time.now.year, label: "Please enter date began Kollel", error: false, include_blank: true %>
      </div>

      <div id="date-select-youth">
        <p>For 16 years old and younger; please provide valid ID</p>
        <%= f.input :date, start_year: Time.now.year - 17, end_year: Time.now.year, label: "Please enter DOB", error: false, include_blank: true %>
      </div>

      <div id="hour">
        <%= f.input :hour, collection: Form::HOURS, error: false, include_blank: true %>
      </div>

      <%= render 'layouts/signature' %>
      </br></br>
      <%= f.hidden_field :base64 %>

      <p>FOR OFFICE USE ONLY:</p>

      <%= f.input :interaction, label: "Interaction type", collection: Form::INTERACTIONS, error: false %>

      <div id="new">
        <%= f.input :new_tag, error: false %>
        <%= f.input :deposit, label: "Cash deposit", error: false %>
        <%= f.input :notes, error: false %>
      </div>

      <div id="exchange">
        <%= f.input :new_tag, error: false %>
        <%= f.input :returned_tag, error: false %>
        <%= f.input :notes, error: false %>
      </div>

      <div id="refund">
        <%= f.input :returned_tag, error: false %>
        <%= f.input :deposit, label: "Cash refund", error: false %>
        <%= f.input :notes, error: false %>
      </div>

      <%= f.submit "Create form", class: "btn btn-primary", id: "save-form" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Form Model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: forms
#
#  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
#  first_name             :string
#  last_name              :string
#  email                  :string
#  address                :string
#  created_at             :datetime         not null
#  updated_at             :datetime         not null
#  member_type            :string
#  phone                  :string
#  signature_file_name    :string
#  signature_content_type :string
#  signature_file_size    :integer
#  signature_updated_at   :datetime
#  base64                 :string
#  children               :string
#  date                   :date
#  hour                   :string
#  interaction            :string
#  new_tag                :string
#  returned_tag           :string
#  deposit                :string
#  notes                  :text
#

class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  VALID_ENGLISH_REGEX = /[a-zA-Z0-9]/
  MEMBERSHIPS = ["Monthly member: $55", "Pay-Per-Use (cash): 15% discount", "Kollel discount: $35", "Youth member: $35", "Monthly with children (Friday's): $55 + $16 per child", "Other" ]
  CHILDREN = ["1 - $16", "2 - $32", "3 - $48", "4 - $64"]
  HOURS = ["6:30-7:30", "7:00-8:00", "7:30-8:30", "8:00-9:00", "8:30-9:30", "9:00-10:00"]
  INTERACTIONS = ["NEW", "EXCHANGE", "REFUND"]

  #paperclip
  has_attached_file :signature, :styles => { medium: "250x500>", thumb: "125x250>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :signature, :content_type => ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"]

  validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, format: { with: VALID_ENGLISH_REGEX }
  before_save :upcase
  validates :email, length: { maximum: 255 }, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, allow_blank: true
  validates :address, presence: true, length: { maximum: 500 }, format: { with: VALID_ENGLISH_REGEX }
  validates :member_type, :phone, :interaction, :base64, presence: true
  simple_phone_number :phone

  validates :date, :hour, presence: true

  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }

  def upcase
    self.first_name = first_name.upcase
    self.last_name = last_name.upcase
  end

end
```

jQuery code:

```
  $('#date-select-kollel, #date-select-youth, #hour, #children').hide();

    $("#form_member_type").change(function() {
      var selected = $('#form_member_type').find(":selected").val();
      if (selected == "Kollel discount: $35") {
        $('#children, #date-select-youth').hide();
        $('#date-select-kollel, #hour').show();
      } else if (selected == "Youth member: $35") {
        $('#date-select-kollel, #children').hide();
        $('#date-select-youth, #hour').show();
      } else if (selected == "Monthly with children (Friday's): $55 + $16 per child") {
        $('#date-select-kollel, #date-select-youth, #hour').hide();
        $('#children').show();
      } else {
        $('#date-select-kollel, #date-select-youth, #hour, #children').hide();
      }
    });

    $('#new, #exchange, #refund').hide();

    $('#form_interaction').change(function() {
      var selected = $('#form_interaction').find(':selected').val();
      if (selected == "NEW") {
        $('#exchange, #refund').hide();
        $('#new').show();
      } else if (selected == "EXCHANGE") {
        $('#new, #refund').hide();
        $('#exchange').show();
      } else if (selected == "REFUND") {
        $('#new, #exchange').hide();
        $('#refund').show();
      }
    });
```

Comment: I recommend you look at the params at each stage.  If you have the better_errors gem, this is easy to do in the browser.  Otherwise, raise, or log the params at each step and see where they are removed or lost.

Comment: Thanks, I will check as soon as I get back to my computer and report my findings

Comment: I would create 'valid_object' specs to make sure strong params and validations are not causing your problems. http://everydayrails.com/2012/03/19/testing-series-rspec-models-factory-girl.html (It's a bit out of date so you may have to change rspec setup).   I would also recommend changing the object name to something besides 'form.'  I worked on a project that had a Form object and it was unnecessarily difficult to talk about.

Comment: The 4 params you say aren't passing have two (or more) `f.input` tags associated with them. IIRC you can't define the same input twice. Perhaps that's what's causing the issue?

Comment: Exactly right! I just realized that when I deleted the second date field. So my question now is, how do I display two different custom date input fields, one for a "Kollel" member, the other for "Youth" member? I have been using jQuery to insert custom date fields based on the selected member type.